# Uninstall JS Sass So I Can Go Back To Ruby Sass

Tags: npm, sass

I installed SASS on my Mac, but wish uninstall it so I can install the old Ruby version which I had on my previous Mac. There seems to be continuing issues where it effectively crashes / stops working out of the blue, which I never experienced on the Ruby version.

I can't see anywhere in the Docs how to uninstall it?

I used `npm install -g sass` to install it on my current machine - but I don't know whether this is a Dart or JS version of SASS ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed the `SASS` using `npm install -g sass` then you can remove it using

```
npm uninstall -g sass
```

That would remove the `js` version of `sass`. In case you still face error's then you can remove your dart version using

```
choco uninstall sass -prerelease
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [NPM Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall), you just need to run `npm uninstall -g sass`.

As for your other question, the NPM package is Dart Sass as stated on its [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass). It also has a section with the [differences from Ruby Sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass#behavioral-differences-from-ruby-sass) so that is something you might be interested in.

Also, I recommend you install the Dart Sass version from Homebrew as [Ruby Sass is at EOL](https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass). You can run `brew install sass/sass/sass` to do that. Again, refer to the differences from Ruby Sass in the link above to make sure your sass is compliant.

Comment: Thanks. There is a bug in Dart Sass which is regularly discussed on the Sass github page which they still can't solve that is making my life a misery. I'll give this a shot tomorrow when I'm back at my computer.